# how density=True works in plt.histogram and numpy.histogram?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to understand how the density =True works in np.histogram and plt.histogram.  Here I have printed the bin counts of my histogram. According to my understanding for calculating probability I need to divide each bin count value e.g 165954 by total number of values (255000) to get probability and this is how it should work when I use density=True. But I'm getting different values. I'm really confused what's going on when I use density=True. How system chooses values along y-axis?

```
`hist, bins= np.histogram(es, bins=10,range=(es.min(),es.max()))
#hist:  [165954,59842,20258,6398,1866,505,131,35,9 ,2]  #bin_counts
sum=np.sum(hist)
#sum:  255000
hist_1 =165954/sum
print("hist_1: ",hist_1) # expected answer: hist_1=0.6508
#Using density=True
hist, bins= np.histogram(es, bins=10,range=(es.min(),es.max()),density=True)
sum = np.sum(hist)
#hist:  [6.04446282e-01,2.17959642e-01, 7.37847402e-02,2.33031280e-02,
6.79644216e-03, 1.83933724e-03, 4.77135007e-04, 1.27478819e-04,
3.27802676e-05, 7.28450392e-06]`
#sum:  0.9287742498750994
```

Comment: Density means that the integral over the histogram is 1. I.e. `np.sum(hist*np.diff(bins)) == 1`.

Comment: So does it mean that after multiplying each bin by its width I get probability?  According to method that I mentioned in my question

Comment: No I'm not calculating it again. But I just want to confirm that my understanding is correct that multiplying each bin with its width gives probability when I use density=True.

Comment: Beside If I have to explain what are these y-axis values? What should I say